# How to make us and uk version of iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, localization

I have seen some localization examples but they were based on languages .

In my case I want to make my application in two versions : us and uk .

For that I can not depend on language as I have seen just English in the settings application .

there is no English(UK) or English(US) .

I want just some minor changes like $ or £ .

These changes I want to do in my code .

So should I make two different builds or there is a way to localize them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking to do is detect different locales instead of languages. Things like currency symbols are supported by way of the `NSLocale` class.

For example to get the currency symbol use:

```
NSString *currencySymbol = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
```

This solves your problem without the user having to configure specifically for your app; chances are good that the default for your app is likely the wrong setting for a good deal of your users with the preference approach.

Comment: Thnks Giao . So will the locale be changed automatically based on the iPhone is us or in uk or I have to give localizable.strings ?

Comment: The localized strings are for language switches. Since you're using the same language in US and UK, that's not necessary. The up side of using locale is that your code will work in other regions where English is used such as Australia and English speaking Canada.

Comment: Can I test in simulator that the above line will give me £ in uk and $ in uk ?

Comment: I'm not certain as I haven't tried that myself. You can test it out by switching your machine's locale setting. Go into Preferences -> Language & Text -> Formats and change your region to UK and run your app in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would probably be to support both with the same build and let the user choose via a preference panel.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer but suppose I don't want give any control to user i.e. the preferences panel then is there any other way to do so ?